# How to build docker image in gitlab-runner and push to local registry? And why --insecure-registry command make --tls=false not working

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

I'm trying to construct gitlab CI/CD with docker.
The goal is building docker image on runner and push to local insecure registry, but docker build keep throwing this error.

```
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=test_project&target=&ulimits=null&version=1": dial tcp: lookup docker on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53: no such host
```

---

This is my gitlab-ci file.

```yaml
...

package:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: package
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  services: 
    - name: docker:20-dind
      alias: docker
      command: ["--tls=false", "--insecure-registry=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_IP:$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT"] # OPTIONS
  script: 
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME . # Error occurred
    - docker tag $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME $DOCKER_REGISTRY_IP:$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY_IP:$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
  cache:
    key: "$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build

...
```

I set priviliged=true to solve first error.

```
[[runners]]
  name = "docker-runner"
  url = "http://192.165.100.2/"
  id = 10
  token = "47e5LRRhgBPcnhfYdDxB"
  token_obtained_at = 2022-12-28T06:50:33Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = true                #set to true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Then first error as solved, but second error has occurred.

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

To solve second error, I added "--tls=false" command to docker:dind service according to [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27300#note_571697847) link.

```
services: 
    - name: docker:20-dind
      alias: docker
      command: ["--tls=false"]
```

Then `no such host` error has solved, But third error has occurred.

```
Get "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

To solve third error, I added `insecure-registry` command according to [this](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-runner-with-insecure-registry/44963/2) link.

```
services: 
    - name: docker:20-dind
      alias: docker
      command: ["--tls=false", "--insecure-registry=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_IP:$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT"]
```

I expected to solve https problem, but error went back to the beginning.

```
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=test_project&target=&ulimits=null&version=1": dial tcp: lookup docker on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53: no such host
```

Why `--insecure-registry` command make `--tls=false` not working?
How to build docker image in gitlab-runner and push to local registry?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding registries in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

You may have config on host like:

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [
        "docker.xxx.xxx:5000",
    ]
}
```

And in your runner config:

```
[[runners]]
  [runners.docker]
    volumes = ["/cache", "/path/to/your daemon.json:/etc/docker/daemon.json"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).